What is StackExchange.options.site.negativeVoteScoreFloor?
While perusing the StackExchange JS global object, I noticed StackExchange.options.site.negativeVoteScoreFloor. From searching the Internet Archive, it seems to have appeared some time around October 2019. I don't see anything that looks related when I put is:q created:2019 [score] in MSE's search bar. I'm guessing it's something that was part of an experiment that didn't get used? I don't really have a purpose for asking, since I've never heard of there being a negative vote score floor being implemented. I'm just asking to satisfy my own curiosity.

It was part of an experiment that never graduated out of beta, based on code comments:
// TODO: This was written for an experiment that did not graduate and can be removed.
function normalizePostScore(score) {
    const negativeVoteScoreFloor = _Shared_options_mod__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"].site.negativeVoteScoreFloor;
    return negativeVoteScoreFloor === null ? score : Math.max(negativeVoteScoreFloor, score);
}


Was is the clamp negative scores to zero experiment?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution most likely, yes. Can't see any reason it would be something else.
